# AzureWebsites cookie issues affecting login

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm a bit baffled as to what is going on with three Azure Websites in the same subscription.

I have

- website1 (via x.azurewebsites.net)
- website1-stage (via x-stage.azurewebsites.net)
- website2 (via CNAME www.foo.com)

If I login to website1 (SimpleMembership) it sets a cookie:.ASPXAUTH

If I login to website1-stage (SimpleMembership) it sets a different valued cookie:.ASPXAUTH

If I go to website2 it REMOVES the .ASPXAUTH cookie from website1 but not from  website1-stage!

What's going on? I need to stop this because users can't be logged in to website1 if they access website2

All three websites have the same ARRAffinity cookie, if that's of any relevance?

I guess they all share the azurewebsites.net domain even via the CNAME? (I hadn't though this was the case but I guess it must be otherwise how can one domain affect another's cookies?)

**edit:** because x-stage.azurewebsites.net (identical to x.azurewebsites.net) is not affected I've assumed Azure is the issue, but in the interest of being thorough I'm exploring some options (*ongoing*):

- www.foo.com/simple.html does not delete the cookie from website1
- www.foo.com/blank.cshtml does not delete the cookie from website1

From here I'm adding in the elements of www.foo.com/ one at a time as this page does cause the cookie to be lost. It most be something!

- www.foo.com/added-javascript.cshtml does not delete the cookie from website1

next test: db access and response (requires new deployment this evening...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started with very simple html, then .cshml. Adding existing page features until loading a page on www.foo.com wiped the cookie/forced a new login from x.azurewebsites.net

The offending code seemed to be this block:

```
<li class="facebook">
    <a target="_blank" title="Join us on Facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/xxxx/yyy?ref=hl#!/zzz?fref=ts">Join us on Facebook</a>
</li>
```

Weirdly, the facebook img was not visible either

```
ul.social li.facebook {
    background: url("../images/Facebook.png") no-repeat scroll left top rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Even in Visual Studio the image preview was not visible for facebook.png, whereas the twitter icon next to it was fine. I though it might be corrupted but it was not.

A VS search (Entire Solution) found no other usages of 'facebook' anywhere, but if I changed the class name to .fb and the image to Fb.png then the image displayed and there was no longer any cookie issues.

How Bizarre! This issue was cross browser (IE Edge and Chrome) and happened on other machines, so I'm still baffled but at least I have got past the issue. It's probably just a Facebook Conspiracy :)

Edit: after further digging the real culprit was finally found:

```
<rules>
   <rule name="BookingRedirect">
     <match url="Book" />
     <action type="Redirect" url="https://xyz.azurewebsites.net/abc" />
</rule>
```